# Getting plain text from Control in winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

The output of htmlEditor1.Html in winform is:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<META content="text/html; charset=unicode" http-equiv=Content-Type>.......
```

I am new to this. I don't know what is the above format.

But i need the output in below format (plain text or html), so that I can save it in a table in DB:

```
"some text checking\r\n"
```

Any suggestion how to get it ?

Comment: The output is HTML and looks like a Microsoft Word document. What WinForms control are you using?

Comment: Dave R, htmlEditor is a third party control :https://yarte.codeplex.com/. As i have to show rich text along with editing capability...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, your third-party control does not support retrieving anything other than the raw HTML.

If you need to parse this to retrieve particular elements' values, then I'd recommend using the HTML Agility Pack. You can add this to your solution using the NuGet package manager (right-click on your solution in the Solution Explorer, select 'Manage NuGet Packages...', and then search for and add the HtmlAgilityPack package).

Once this is done, you can process the HTML in your code. For example, if you wanted to retrieve the text in each of the paragraphs, you could do something like:

```
// Create an HTML Document to parse
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
// Load in the third party control's HTML output
doc.LoadHtml(htmlEditor1.Html);
// Retrieve the paragraph (p) nodes of the document
List<HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode> paragraphNodes = doc.DocumentNode.DescendantNodes()
    .Where(node => node.Name == "p")
    .ToList();

// Process each of the paragraph nodes in turn
foreach (var node in paragraphNodes)
{
    // Output the paragraph text
    // TODO: save the text in the database...
    Console.WriteLine(node.InnerText);
}
```

Note: if the HTML does represent a Word document, the nodes may very well have different names to the above, possibly with namespace prefixes and a colon. You'll need to change the `node.Name == "p"` code in the example above with `node.Name == "<prefix>:<nodename>"` to be able to process these, e.g. `node.Name == "w:p"`.